# Python List Wrangling

Tags: python, csv, tableau-api, data-analysis

I take a list that looks like this

```
[[x, a, d], [y], [z,f]]
```

It wrangles the list by this

```
#tag to print is the raw JSON
        for tagElement in tagToPrint[x]:
            if tagElement not in allConstrainedTagList:
                if v == 0:
                    topicTagConcat = [tagElement]
                    topicTagToPrint[x] = tagElement
                    v = v + 1
                elif v >= 1:
                    topicTagConcat = [topicTagConcat, tagElement]
                    topicTagToPrint[x] = topicTagConcat
                    v = v + 1
```

which then uses this

```
with open("output.csv", 'wb') as outcsv:
    #configure writer to write standard csv file
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(['Topic Tag', ..... ])
    while x < y:
        writer.writerow(rowPrinter[x])
        x = x + 1
```

to print this out

```
ID ColA ColB ColC
1   X    A    D
2   Y         
3   Z         F
```

How can I analyze A & B & C together as one column? X, Y, Z, A, B, C are 
the same column. It is going in tableau.

Comment: `csv_writer.writerows(my_list)`

Comment: Are those letters strings, or are they meant to be Python variables?

Comment: right I am already doing that, and it writes out to seperate columns, and thus cannot analyze within tableau

Comment: @kindall strings, its the output from my code, I can paste if needed

Comment: Code added to the original post